# How can the neutron have any 'electric polarizability'?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, polarization, neutrons

If a neutron has no identifiable electric charge or polarization, as far as anybody has been able to determine, how can it have a value for 'electric polarizability'?

Wikipedia has a value listed that is only smaller than that for the proton....  I'm confused....

Comment: I realize that Sean E. Lake asked a similar question....

Answer (score 3):

The neutron has no **net** charge, but it is made of charged **components**, namely quarks. An electric field can slightly change the density distributions of different quark species in the neutron, leading to an induced electric dipole moment.

Similarly, atoms have no net charge, but are made of a nucleus and electrons, which have charge. An electric field distorts the electron cloud and gives the atom an electric dipole moment.